# How does tunable consistency work in distributed systems like Elastic-Search or Cassandra?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, cassandra, couchbase, distributed

Tunable consistency means that when an update is received by a `master-node`, then the master need not wait for all the `replica-nodes` to copy the same update. How many replicas need to be `in-sync` can be configured by the user.

If the above is true, then consider the following scenario:

1. A system has one master and 5 replicas and tunable consistency is set to 2.
2. An update arrives on the master and is written to the master and 1 replica.
3. The master is unable to write to any other replica, even though they are online.
4. Since tunable consistency is not met, master fails the update.
5. What happens to the replica that already succeeded in copying the update?

Note that I have deliberately avoided specifying any particular distributed system because this is a common pattern across many systems like Elastic-Search, Solr, Couchbase and Cassandra. Do these systems have a rollback feature like a database?

Comment: You're asking an implementation specific question and deliberately avoiding specifying any particular system. 

In Cassandra's case, if the master KNOWS (through Gossip) that there are insufficient replicas available at the time the mutation arrives, it will fail immediately. If it thinks it has enough UP replicas, and then they time out/fail, then it may be partially applied (some replicas may have the write, but others may not).

Comment: Jeff, I do not want to know the implementation for each system and the systems are listed just for example sake. The question is generic enough for many distributed system and I am assuming that most of them will be handling it the same way (Otherwise how many different ways could there be? Just a mention of those ways would be nice to know too). My question specific to Cassandra is: "How does Cassandra ensure that failed update is *removed* from the replicas that succeeded? If it does not do anything, system will become inconsistent soon."

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that your question isn't generic enough. The answer is necessarily implementation specific and relies on false premise (that there exists a master). In the case of Cassandra, it doesn't attempt to ensure that the failed update is removed from the replicas. There exist tools (LWT/BATCH) that provide better guarantees, but they aren't the defaults.

Comment: Interesting to know that Cassandra just allows the failed update to remain in the replicas. If there are a couple of such cases, then every replica would be different from each other in no time. I guess other systems like ES, Solr etc too do the same thing because AFAIK, they too have no rollback commands.

Comment: You may have a misconception about primary node /replica node in cassandra. The coordinator figures out who the primary owner of the partition is and who the replicas belong to - then it sends out the data to all of them simultaneously. If any of the nodes are down, then the data is stored in the hints table until the node is back up or until it expires (default = 3 hr). I know you didn't want to be implementation-specific, but an understanding of cassandra basics is helpful.